# Cypher query (or APOC procedure) that samples all labels and returns graph representing x% of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working with a graph that has many object types (e.g. LABELS).
I would like to be able to run a query that samples every label, and returns a small but representative set of data containing nodes (and relationships) for each label.  Has anyone seen or achieved this?
Thanks,  John

Comment: Of interest: [Viewing schema data with APOC Procedures](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/viewing-schema-data-with-apoc/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns for each label, five nodes associated with this label :

```
call db.labels() yield label
call apoc.cypher.run("match (x:`"+label+"`) RETURN x LIMIT 5", null) yield value
return label, collect(value.x) AS nodes
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for!  Thank you Christophe!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your model you could display your complete label structure as graph by the Cypher statement `CALL apoc.meta.graph();`.

For a representative set of data for each label we should know your underlying model or rather labels. I could imagine a solution based on the `Limit` clause:

```
MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
WITH n, r
  LIMIT 5000
RETURN n, r;
```